# Float precision differs between elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to read a dataframe from a csv, do some calculations with it and then export the results to another csv. While doing that I noticed that the value `8.1e-202` is getting changed to `8.1000000000000005e-202`. But all the other numbers are represented correctly.

## Example:

### A example.csv looks like this:

```
id,e-value
ID1,1e-20
ID2,8.1e-202
ID3,9.24e-203
```

If I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
df.iloc[1]["e-value"]
>>> 8.1000000000000005e-202

df.iloc[2]["e-value"]
>>> 9.24e-203
```

Why is `8.1e-202` being altered but `9.24e-203` isn't?

I tried to change the datatype that pandas is using from the default

```
df["e-value"].dtype
>>> dtype('float64')
```

to numpy datatypes like this:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("./temp/test", dtype={"e-value" : np.longdouble})
```

but this will just result in:

```
df.iloc[1]["e-value"]
>>> 8.100000000000000522e-202
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? I can't replicate this problem with any other number. Everything bigger or smaller than 8.1e-202 seems to work normally.

**EDIT:**
To specify my problem. I am aware that floats are not perfect. My actual problem with this is that once I write the dataframe back to a csv the resulting file will then look like this:

```
id,e-value
ID1,1e-20
ID2,8.1000000000000005e-202
ID3,9.24e-203
```

And I need the second row to be **ID2,8.1e-202**
I "fixed" this by just formatting this column before I write the csv, but I'm unhappy with this solution since the formatting will change other elements to something scientific notation where it was just a normal float.

```
def format_eval(e):
    return "{0:.1e}".format(e)

df["e-value"] = df["e-value"].apply(lambda x: format_eval(x))
```

Comment: This isn't a different precision - it's the usual 'floats are not exact' issue.

Comment: @hpaulj this isn't the usual floats are not exact issue, because there's an attempt to make the binary value be the closest to the desired decimal value.  In this case that would be 8.0999999999999e-202, not 8.1000000000000005e-202.

Comment: Loading this text with `np.genfromtxt`  didn't do anything unusual for this number with a 'f8' dtype.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, `np.genfromtxt` loads this without this problem.  There's something about `pd.read_csv` that produces this unusual value.  That reader has a lot of parameters. `float_precision` indicates it's doing its own float conversion, not the usual python one that `numpy` uses.   If I load it with `object` dtype, and later convert with `astype` the number is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Float number representation is something not so simple. Not every real number can be represented and almost all (relatively speaking) are actually approximations. Is not like integers, the precision varies and python has a precision undefined float really.

Each floating point standar will have their own set of real numbers that can represent exactly. There's no work around.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision

If the problem really is the arithmetic or comparison, you should consider if error will grow or decrease. For example multiplying by large numbers can grow the representation error.

And also, when comparing you should do things like **math.is_close**. Basically comparing the distance between the numbers.

If you are trying to represent and operate real numbers, that aren't irrational numbers. Like integers, fractions or decimal numbers with finite digits, you can also consider cast to the proper digit representation like: int, decimal or fraction.

See this for further ideas:
[https://davidamos.dev/the-right-way-to-compare-floats-in-python/#:~:text=How%20To%20Compare%20Floats%20in%20Python&text=If%20abs(a%20%2D%20b),rel_tol%20keyword%20argument%20of%20math](https://davidamos.dev/the-right-way-to-compare-floats-in-python/#:%7E:text=How%20To%20Compare%20Floats%20in%20Python&text=If%20abs(a%20%2D%20b),rel_tol%20keyword%20argument%20of%20math).